# Could not install Harf Buzz - text shaping engine

Tags: python, unicode, fonts, opentype, harfbuzz

I am using harfbuzz for shaping fonts. I am a newbie to python. I followed the instructions that was given in [Harf Buzz](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/blob/master/README.python.md)

but i couldnt understand these line

> Make sure you have the installation lib dir in **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**, as needed for the linker to find the library.

---

> Then make sure you also have **GI_TYPELIB_PATH** pointing to the resulting $prefix/lib/girepository-* directory.

in the Readme file. Due to this i could not execute **src/sample.py**. 
Because of this i get

---

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 8, in <module>
    from gi.repository import HarfBuzz as hb
ImportError: cannot import name HarfBuzz`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which os are you installing on?

Comment: installing in ubuntu

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. The capitalized words refer to *environment settings*. Look up how to verify and, optionally change, them for your OS.

Comment: Rather than asking that here, did you (also) ask this over on the official place to ask questions for Harfbuzz? If you're getting confused, then it is highly unlikely you are the only one, so head over to https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz, go the issues, and ask the project maintainers whether they can clarify this in the documentation. This answer should not be on Stackoverflow, it should be immediately available to everyone in the Harfbuzz readme, so they don't have to google and/or visit SO just to get this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu already has packaged the gobject bindings for harfbuzz. You do not need to compile from source.

```
› sudo apt install python-gobject-2-dev gobject-introspection libharfbuzz-gobject0
› python3 -c 'import gi; gi.require_version("HarzBuzz", "0.0"); from gi.repository import HarzBuzz'
```